# form element not being printed out

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm fetching some HTML codes from a PHP function and printing it. Something like this:

```
// the html code
<div><?php echo $this->create_form(); ?></div>

//the php code
function create_form()
{
    return '<form method="POST" id="myform"><input blah blah.../></form>';
}
```

The problem is that, all elements "inside" the form gets printed, but the form itself is not! For example:

```
<div><input blah blah.../></div>
```

If I change "form" with something else like "div", then it gets printed, but whenever I put form element it just doesn't want to be printed!!

Comment: What do you mean by printed? the text of the controls itself or when the controls are generated?

Comment: The PHP method is returning a string that contains the form element and other stuff...I'm echoing the string between that DIV. That's what I meant by print...

Comment: From the looks of it when you run your code it should create the form element and one input box in a browser. When you view source then you would see the `form` element is present - http://codepad.viper-7.com/2fcQ9X

Comment: That's the point..there's no form in source! So there must be something in my code that does this to the form...

Comment: Does printing a form inside another form might be the problem?

Comment: No, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms.

Comment: Well I found something...If I put an empty <form></form> before those codes, then the form will appear!! Strange!

Comment: It's working fine at my end.

Comment: It's totally working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div><?php echo create_form(); ?></div>
<?php
//the php code
function create_form()
{
    return '<form method="POST" id="myform"><input class="namefield" type="text"/></form>';
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your and above code??

Comment: $this-> does not declare

Comment: He may be using the function in a class.

Comment: yeah may be you are right he might use the function in class